# Using a Gauss sum to show that $p$ is of the form $x^2 + xy +3y^2$ if and only if $p \equiv 1, 3, 4, 5, 9 \pmod{11}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

> Let $p \neq 11$ be an odd prime, and $\zeta$ an $11$th root of unity.  Let $g$ be the Gauss sum $$g = \sum\limits_{i=1}^5 \zeta^{i^2} = \zeta + \zeta^4 + \zeta^9 + \zeta^5 + \zeta^3$$
>
> We may assume that $(2g+1)^2 = -11$, so $g$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-11}}{2}]$.
> (a) Show that $-11$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $g^p = p$ if and only if $p$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> (b) Show that $p$ is of the form $x^2 + xy + 3y^2$ if and only if $p$ is a square modulo $11$.

So (a) seems to be a special case of quadratic reciprocity, but the point is to prove the result without using quadratic reciprocity.  The ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$ is $A = \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega = \frac{1+\sqrt{-11}}{2}$, and the norm of an element $a+b\omega$ is $a^2 + ab + 3b^2$.

We know that a prime $p$ splits in $A$ if and only if $X^2 - X + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has a solution (since $X^2 -X + 3$ is the minimal polynomial of $\omega$).  If $p$ doesn't split in this ring, then it remains prime, and the ring $A/(p)$ is a field of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  Also, if $p$ is not a square modulo $-11$, then $$g^p \equiv \sum\limits_{i=1}^5 \zeta^{pi^2} \pmod{pA}$$ which is the sum of $\zeta$ raised to the powers of all the nonresidues modulo $11$ (product of nonresidue and a residue is a nonresidue), so $g+g^p \equiv 1 + \zeta + \cdots + \zeta^{10} = \frac{\zeta^{11}-1}{\zeta-1} = 0 \pmod{pA}$.

Am I on the right track?  I seem to be able to do things with congruence modulo $pA$ (where $pA$ is either a direct sum of two $\mathbb{Z}p\mathbb{Z}$s or a field with $p^2$ elements), but I still am not sure how we can transfer the results about congruence to results about the ring.

Comment: I might be wrong but these steps (to compute $g^2,g^p$ and relate them with the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{11}{p}\right)$) are exactly the ones used in a classical proof of the quadratic reciprocity law.

Comment: Point $(b)$ follows from the fact that $x^2\pm xy+3y^2$ is the only reduced quadratic form of discriminant $-11$.

Comment: What happened [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041303/)?