# Product of a non negative decreasing function with a Lebesgue integrable function on $[0, 1]$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function on $[0, 1]$ such that $$\int^t_0f(x)dx \leq 0$$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$ and $\phi : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a non-negative decreasing function then show that $\phi f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1]$ and $$\int^t_0f(x)\phi(x)dx \leq 0 - (*)$$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$. $$$$
I showed that $f\phi$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1]$ but I'm unable to prove $(*)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lebesgue differentiation theorem?

Comment: No I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041303/42969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\int_0^{x} g \leq \int_0^x f$ and $\phi$ is nonincreasing then $\int_0^{\infty} \phi g \leq \int_0^\infty \phi f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041303/if-int-0x-g-leq-int-0x-f-and-phi-is-nonincreasing-then-int-0-inf)

Comment: The proof in the above link is for the domain $(0, \infty)$  but i have to prove it for every interval $[0, t]$, $t \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: @user671269: That does not matter, you can extend the domain of $f$ to $(0, \infty)$ and define $f(x) = 0$ for $x > 1$.

Comment: I am unable to understand the steps, can you please give a complete proof ?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an tweak of Did's answer.

Define a sequence of step functions by letting $\displaystyle I_k=\left [{k\over n},{k+1\over n}\right )$ and $\displaystyle \phi _n=\sum \limits _k\phi \left ({k\over n}\right ){\bf 1}_{I_k}$. We have
$0\leq \phi _n(x)\leq \phi (0)$ for all $x,n$, and $\phi _n(x)\downarrow \phi (x)$ for ae. $x\in [0,1]$.

The Dominated Convergence Theorem shows that $\displaystyle \int f\phi _n\to \int f\phi$.

We can write $\displaystyle \phi _n(x)=\mu [x,1]=\int \limits _x^1d\mu$ for some measure $\mu$. To see this, let $\displaystyle \mu _n=\phi (1)\delta _1+\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\left (\phi \left ({k\over n}\right )-\phi \left ({k+1\over n}\right )\right )\delta _{k  \over n}$, where $\delta _y$ is the Dirac measure at $y$.
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \limits _0^tf(x)\phi _n(x)\,dx & = & \int \limits _0^tf(x)\int _x^1d\mu (s)\,dx \\
& = & \int \limits _0^1\int _0^1{\bf 1}_{[0,t]}(x){\bf 1}_{[x,1]}(s)f(x)\,d\mu (s)\,dx \\
& = & \int \limits _0^1\int \limits _0^1{\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(s){\bf 1}_{[0,\min(s,t)]}(x)f(x)\,dx\,d\mu(s) \\
& = & \int \limits _0^1\left (\int \limits _0^1{\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(s){\bf 1}_{[0,\min(s,t)]}(x)f(x)\,dx\right )\,d\mu (s) \\
& = & \int \limits _0^1\left (\int \limits _0^{\min (s,t)}f(x)\,dx\right )\,d\mu (s) \\
& \leq & 0.
\end{eqnarray}
Then the result follows from the Dominated Convergence Theorem.